# How to add active class in tab-pane portfolio item in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am making a dynamic portfolio section in wordpress. Site live link is here http://www.nayeemriddhi.info/testproject/portfolio/.
But the fact is when i open a portfolio item and select item from left side, for the first portfolio image it is working, the view portion of right side.but for the second and third image view portion of right side it is not working. although it has been added active class in static in code,it is working for the first image, why i don't know.Now i want to add active class dynamically in query3 loop portion for that item. Is it possible to add. the code is below....

```
 <section>            
<div class="container gal-container">
  <?php
    args = array(
       'post_type' => 'custom_portfolio',
       'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        );
      // the query
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
         // The Loop   
         if ( $query->have_posts() )  ?>
          <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ; ?> 
             <!-- Item-->        
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 co-xs-12 gal-item">
                <div class="box">
                  <a class="trigger" data-iziModal-open="#modal<?php the_ID(); ?>">
           <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_image', true);   ?>">
                  </a>

                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Modal-->
              <div id="modal<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="iziModal portfolio" data-izimodal-title="Portfolio Title" data-izimodal-subtitle="Web Design" style="max-width: 1200px important;">

                  <div class="col_one_third p-20">
                      <?php

                        $args2 = array(
                        'post_type' => 'custom_portfolio',
                        'posts_per_page' => '6',
                          );
                         // the query
                         $query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
                          // The Loop   
                         if ( $query2->have_posts() )  ?>
                        <?php while ( $query2->have_posts() ) : 
                          $query2->the_post() ; ?>

                     <div class="col_half p-10">
                        <a  href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>b" data-toggle="tab">
                                  <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_image', true);   ?>" class="portfolio-thumb"/>
                        </a>       
                      </div>

             <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();  ?>

                        <div class="col_full p-10">
                          <div class="portfolio-links">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-new" target="_blank">Launch Website</a>    

<a href="#request-quote-form" class="btn btn-danger request-quote-modal">Request a Quote</a>
                       </div>
                      </div> 

                  </div>        

                  <div class="col_two_third col_last">
                      <div class="tab-content">                    
                          <?php

                        $args3 = array(
                        'post_type' => 'custom_portfolio',
                        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                          );
                         // the query
                         $query3 = new WP_Query( $args3 );
                          // The Loop   
                         if ( $query3->have_posts() )  ?>
                        <?php while ( $query3->have_posts() ) : 
                          $query3->the_post() ; ?>        
                          <div class="tab-pane active" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>b">
                              <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_image', true);   ?>" class="img-responsive"/>                         
                          </div>
                        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();  ?>                            
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>        
                 <!-- Item End-->                
             <?php  endwhile; wp_reset_query();   ?>                  
            </div>        
          </section>Thanks for help....
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you have the same ID for the tabs. IDs are unique, you should change it for every project.

Comment: IDs are unique, but need to add active class for selected item, please see for the first item it has active class separately for unique item

Comment: They are not unique. I looked into the inspector. Your lightbox has every item opened at all time, you have to change the ID for every one. For your items you have: 25b, 23b and 21b on every item. When you click it on the second or third it only works for the first one, because that's where the first ID is.

Comment: there is two portion , <div class="col_one_third p-20">    </div>

Comment: <div class="col_two_third col_last> </div>

Comment: when i call 1 , it goes to col_last section

Comment: for active class it is not working , please see it, not id , ids are unique dynamically

Comment: I'm sorry but your IDs are not at all unique. Also, the images on the left side the link is referring to the ID of the right image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174398/discussion-between-nayeem-hyder-riddhi-and-yomisimie).

Comment: please check it chatroom

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174398/discussion-between-nayeem-hyder-riddhi-and-yomisimie

Comment: there are only three image , and there IDs are 21, 23, 25 , isn't unique?

Comment: Browser console is showing JS errors, fix those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the IDs of the second and third modal. Currently you have the same ID everywhere and the image changes on the first one too.
Add another ID from the url that opens up the modal